# Laravel Database Sessions in Horizontally Scaled Enviornment

Tags: php, session, laravel

I'm using Laravel in a multiple frontend/application server enviornment (i.e. -- two web servers behind a load balancer).

I'm debugging a problem where the Laravel application loses its session data after a few requests to the server.  We're using database sessions with a single MySQL database instance.

I notice every time I reload the page, the `laravel_session` cookie changes. One one page refresh is looks like this

```
eyJpdiI6I-mRudUNnM0ZpQzdxYmNyaWw0d21nWFE9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiazVDQTVuZ0IzYUg5V0l3czBxaFl6bFRrXC9aTjFmT0VBeGVDYXg1REZQM2pIS1U0U1JCSVVreHprYU44ZjhKQTU4OTVUUGxpXC9qbWZpd0FcL2NtXC9ST25B-PT0iLCJtYWMiOiJ-hZWYxNTU4MDY0ODQxODViNDRjMjQzZGE1ZDQwZDA0YzQ0ZDY1YjE3YWE3YTc3ZjcwNTg4NGE3NDhhMWMzMGU0In0
```

Then reloading the page again it looks like this

```
eyJpdiI6I-nFjRjN1TGp0Q3Z3VmlrOG1PQlwveDF3PT0iLCJ2YWx1ZSI6IkVRYkpuWXFIVms5YnBwRXU2b1wvMFZSbW14RkVTZm8yVEpnaHRiOEhpWnlJWm9OM0JRR1wvYUI1VWhmeGYxQm0yaEFrc25PZUVcL3NSZ0RtUytzWHR3THp3-PT0iLCJtYWMiOiJ-jNTQ1YjM0MTkwZDVmM2RlMTAxYmNkMjAzMTY1NzVjMDExNTkxODAyZDM0YmQ5ZTk5NzFiNmY1YjQxYzE3ZjY1In0
```

The `-` is my addition to show that there's sections that stay the same.

Questions:

1. <s>Is this changing session ID standard Laravel behavior?</s>
2. Will Laravel's 4.2 database sessions work out of the box in the multiple frontend web server environment?
3. Where in Laravel's core does the session implementation live so I can poke at it myself?

Re: #1, per [ceejayoz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1902010/ceejayoz), the `laravel_session` cookie is re-encrypted on every server request, and this encryption includes a bit of randomization -- which means the changing `laravel_session` value is standard Laravel behavior.

Comment: If you do `php artisan tinker` and then `Crypt::decrypt('your session cookie contents');` does it show you session data?

Comment: +1 for useful information -- If I decrypt the session contents I get the session_id (I'm using the database driver, not the cookie driver).  Do you know where Laravel encrypts/decrypts the contents of this cookie?  If the day/time is part of the crypt salt that would explain the changing values.

Comment: Laravel encrypts all cookies in `Illuminate\Cookie\Guard`, I believe. I think the salt is randomized but don't quote me on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is this changing session ID standard Laravel behavior?

Yes, this is standard Laravel behavior -- the `Illuminate\Cookie\Guard` Middleware layer automatically encrypts the application cookies using an object instantiated from the `Illuminate\Encryption\Encrypter` class, which includes [creating an initialization vector from a random source](http://php.net/mcrypt_create_iv).

```
#File: vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Guard.php
public function encrypt($value)
{           
    $iv = mcrypt_create_iv($this->getIvSize(), $this->getRandomizer());
    //...
    $value = base64_encode($this->padAndMcrypt($value, $iv));
    //...
}
```

> Will Laravel's 4.2 database sessions work out of the box in the multiple frontend web server environment?

From what I've seen, yes.  Laravel's database sessions are ID based, and the ID can survive a load balancer swapping a user between servers, assuming the same application and configuration are sent to each sever.

> Where in Laravel's core does the session implementation live so I can poke at it myself?

Laravel's Session handling is setup in the Session Middleware

```
#File: vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Session/Middleware.php
```

For the curious, sessions ended up a red herring here.  The problem was a form URL setup to post to an insecure URL from a secure URL.  Browsers will drop your cookies when this happens, which meant the session ID got regenerated.  So, this was still indirectly caused by our load balancing setup, and that our monkey patched `Request` object didn't account for urls generated with Laravel's `url->to()`.  Our solution was to switch the form URL generation to use a named `route`, and configure the route as `https` only in `app/routes.php`

Comment: Hey Alan, I'm seeing some key collision errors around sessions in the app logs on a similar setup. Looking at /Illuminate/Session/Store.php it appears this could be possible if two sessions are created at the exact same microsecond on two webservers. Did you run into anything like this?

Comment: @CollinJames I never did, but reading over the uniqid implementation (http://php.net/uniqid) is seems like what you're describing would be possible in a multiple frontend/app server environment.

Answer (score 2):

This can have many reasons, but the most likely one is that your load balancer directs you to another server which doesn't know your session id and therefore generates a new session for you.

The solution to this is to use a shared key store like [redis](http://redis.io/). Laravel has [native support for redis](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/redis), so there shouldn't be much effort to get it up and running and your session cache is then shared between your apps. Redis is very performant and easy to set up, so your servers wont be heavily overloaded by it. You may want to consider a RAM upgrade depending on the count of sessions under high load.

Of course you could also move your session cache dir to a network share. This may be inperformant and wasted effort, but your competitors will have a good laugh ;)

EDIT: Also make sure that **both apps have the same encryption key**.